# withCount() doesn't include deleted rows?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

How can I make `withCount('comments')` also include all deleted/trashed rows?

For example, if I have 5 comments, and I delete 1, I still expect `withCount('comments')` to return 5, but instead it's returning 4.

My full query looks something like this:

```
$query = Post::withTrashed()
    ->withCount('comments')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Please mark your question as answered if any answer worked out for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this

```
$query = Post::withCount('comments')
    ->withTrashed()
    ->get();
```

**OR**

```
$query = DB::table('post')
         ->select('comments', DB::raw('count(*) as comments'))
         ->get();
```

Hope this work for you!

Answer (score 1):

Since laravel doesn't propose a way to filter the relation when using `withCount`, a clean solution would be to declare the relation and add the `withTrashd()` to it.

In **Post.php**

```php
public function commentsWithTrashed()
{
    return $this->comment()->withTrashed();
}
```

Now you can use the `withCount` on it.

```php
$query = Post::withTrashed()
    ->withCount('commentsWithTrashed')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to count

```
$query = Post::withCount(['comments'=> function ($query) {$query->onlyTrashed();])
         ->get();
```

it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the withTrashed method:

```
>withTrashed()
```

Comment: I'm not trying to get the trashed rows, I'm trying to get a COUNT of all rows, including trashed rows.

Comment: And something like this doesn't work? $count = Model::where('column','value')->withTrashed()->count();

Comment: If I can, I'd rather have it all done under the same query.

Comment: Now that I see your full query, I would try $query = Post::withCount('comments')->withTrashed()
    ->get();
If that doesn't work you will probably have to use withTrashed() on the relationship in the model. You can define a second relationship for this.