# laravel withCount get likes that have been deleted

Tags: php, laravel

This function is not getting a count for posts that have been deleted. It's just getting a count of total likes but it disregards if `deleted_at is = null`

I'm using soft deletes for my likes.

I'm trying to count likes for a post with likes where deleted_at is == to null (meaning likes that are not deleted).

it seems to ignore the what i have and get a total of all likes regardless if its been soft deleted.

here is what i currently have.

```
public function getTotalLikes(Post $post, User $user)
{

    $likes = Post::withCount('likes')->first();

    if($likes->deleted_at != NULL){
        return 'no likes';
    }


    else{
        return $likes->count();
    }

    $response = new Response(json_encode($likes));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: `withCount` should respect soft deletion, as [indicated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44551311/withcount-doesnt-include-deleted-rows). Are you certain you've got soft deletion properly configured for likes? Does `Like::all()` show soft-deleted records?

Comment: let me try that and yes i do have soft deleted configured properly, here is the funny thing, if i misspell deleted_at on the function above, it will show no error it will proceed with the function –

Comment: it ignores this `if($likes->deleted_at != NULL){
            return 'no likes';
        }`

part

Comment: can you show likes() relation ? maybe you have withTrashed there...

Comment: i have a heroku for this sign up and login and see the network tab 

 https://morning-depths-45941.herokuapp.com/

Comment: it should show number of likes that are not deleted

Comment: you to see my likes schema ?

Comment: in the console it shows likes:0 when a post has been liked, you see what i mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach :

```
public function getTotalLikes(Post $post)
{
    $likes = Like::where('post_id', $post->id)->get();

    if($likes->count()){
        return $likes->count();
    }
    return 'no likes';
}
```

In the Js :

```
$scope.getLikecount = function(post){
    $http.get('post/'+post.id+'/getTotalLikes').then(function(result){

        console.log("likes:"+result.data);

    });

};
```

In the routes file :

```
Route::get('post/{post}/getTotalLikes', 'PostController@getTotalLikes');
```

Side note about soft delete in laravel :

When you do things like this :

```
Like::where('post_id', $post->id)->get();
```

Laravel exclude automaticly deleted ones,
if you want **even the deleted** ones you can add `withTrashed()` :

```
Like::withTrashed()->where('post_id', $post->id)->get();
```

And when you want **ONLY deleted** ones use `onlyTrashed()` :

```
Like::onlyTrashed()->where('post_id', $post->id)->get();
```

Comment: hey mate :) any reason you commented out the response ?

Comment: yes there is one :p, because you have done `return 'no likes';` or `return $postWithCount->likes_count;` so the response block is a dead code ;) (will not be reached ) !

Comment: im testing this out one sec

Comment: yeah i tried `$count = Likes::where('post_id', $post->id)->count();` and it just renders out 0 when there is a post that has been liked

Comment: i can push this heroku one sec

Comment: check the console log for better understanding

 https://morning-depths-45941.herokuapp.com/

Comment: sign up and login  obviously

Comment: sorry i was busy ok wait i will see :)

Comment: thank you for showing me the power using the console.log